# Is algorithm with more than $2^{word size}$ words secure?

Tags: algorithm-design, feistel-network, pseudo-random-permutation

Let's say we have a feistel cipher or feistel pseudo-random permutation with 8-bit function (S-box) similar to Treyfer, but with much bigger block size like 16MB. Here is example of such pseudo-random permutation:

```
extern const uint8_t s[256];
uint8_t x[16777216];
unsigned int r;
unsigned int i;
uint8_t t = x[0];

for (r = 0; r < 16; r++)
{
    for (i = 1; i < 16777216; i++)
        t = x[i] ^= s[t];

    t = x[0] ^= s[t] ^ r;
}
```

Do we have to worry about inter collisions? Is any algorithm with more than $2^{word size}$ words secure?

Comment: What are "inter collisions"? $\:$ Do you have a formal definition for the $wordsize$ of an algorithm? $\hspace{.82 in}$

Comment: Do you assume that the wordsize is half the blocksize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't include a key; I'll assume that the sbox is the key.

However, even with that assumption, it still doesn't meet the general expected requirements for a block cipher.  In the decrypt direction, any one byte of the decrypted result depends only on 16 (!) bytes of the ciphertext block.

This can be seen by considering the inverse of the round function:

```
t = x[16777215]
x[0] ^= s[t] ^ r;

for (i = 16777215; i > 0; i--)
{
    t = x[i - 1];
    x[i] ^= s[t];
}
```

Going through the above logic, we see that the result of `x[i]` depends only on the initial value of `x[i-1]` and `x[i]`; it is independent of all the other initial values of `x`.  So, running through the above logic for 16 rounds, we see that the final value `x[i]` depends solely on the initial values of `x[i-15]` through `x[i]`

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I forgot to mention it is not a block cipher, it is pseudo-random permutation.

Comment: As you pointed out algorithm is broken, however you did not answer my question. Question is generic, not specific to this algorithm, which is only example. So let's say it has $2^{32}$ rounds.

Comment: If you want a generic answer, then yes, it is believed to be possible to create a secure cipher (and assuming the block size is large does not invalidate that belief)